# SqlYog not enclosing strings when copying database tables to another db

Tags: sqlyog

An operation that I have done countless times suddenly stopped working: copying tables from one db to another one in SqlYog: the sql strings are not being enclosed in quotes, like:

```
insert into `testdb`.`countries` (`id`,`land`,`group`,`pos`,`ccode`,`cc`)
values (1, Argentinië, C, 1, ARG, ar),(2, Australië, D, 2, AUS, au) [...];
```

This generates error 1064. Is there a setting that may fix this?

Comment: It is an incompatibility issue with MariaDB 11.3. Exporting from MariaDB 10.11 works as expected.